# Remmina RDP key remapping

Tags: linux, keyboard, remote-desktop, remmina

Remmina is a wonderful piece of software and I use it a lot on my work. The only problem is key mapping. I am really used to working in DWM window manager, which utilizes windows key to switch panes.
So, when I switch from a pane where remmina is opened, the keypress is also sent to a RDP window, which opens unnecessary windows or even logs me off.
Naturally, this is very annoying.

Remmina uses freeRDP as an RDP plugin but I can't find a way to remap keys in it - there's no **/usr/share/freerdp directory**, which should contain all the configs so I presume remmina pushes its own configs from somewhere.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: [The wiki on the github](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Keyboard) seems to suggest that, because of how MS intended RDP to work, FreeRDP (the RDP library remmina uses) just sends the server the raw scancodes after telling the server what keyboard layout is being used locally. I think the idea is to make it more like Windows is actually running on your bare hardware. I also fear that this means you’d need to figure out how to remap the keys in Windows itself or write a patch against FreeRDP/Remmina to somehow start respecting `xmodmap`. I'd like to know a workaround too ;-).

Comment: See also [Remap key within remmina doesn't work on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936791).

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1822331 suggests to go to Edit → Preferences → RDP → Use client keyboard mapping. But even when I check that box, my mapping of capslock onto Super_L isn’t seen by remmina.

Answer (score 2):

[I've just implemented this feature in Remmina](https://gitlab.com/Remmina/Remmina/-/merge_requests/2304), therefore any version prior 1.4.21, that as of Today is still not yet released, cannot remap scancodes.

In the meanwhile the only temporary solution is to use xfreerdp if you have at least the version 2.3.0

Comment: is this problem solve?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to find any workaround, unfortunately. Solved the issue with simply disabling the winkey as described here
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216893

I guess there should be some way to automatize the process (you can't copy into REG_BINARY fields in the regedit and counting and typing in all the zeroes was not an easy process) but I never bothered to find it out.